# How do I trim the white pixels surrounding my graphics in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas content and I would like to remove all the white (NOT transparent) pixels surrounding my graphics in it.

However, after a lot of searches, I only found functions that could remove transparent pixels. But I need to find a way to remove the white pixels (R=255,G=255,B=255,A=255) because the canvas I'm going to work with is a white-background one.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us a code snippet with a canvas that is filled in?

Comment: Also, quick google search for "trim white around canvas", gave me this result: https://gist.github.com/remy/784508

Comment: This function in github only trims transparent pixels, not white ones.

Comment: I'm quite sure, that you can simply change one line in there, and check for white pixels instead of transparent: `if (pixels.data[i+3] !== 0) {`

Comment: Oh. Just made it. Thanks!